# Difference between using ternary operator and if condition

Tags: java

I was solving a code challenge (covert a number from decimal to binary and then print the consecutive # of 1s in a binary # ) on HackerRank.com and I wrote the following code below to solve the challenge (see below).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    String binaryNum = "";
    int count = 0, maxCount = 0; 
    StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder(); 
    while(n != 0){
        binaryNum = Integer.toString(n % 2);
        binary.append(binaryNum);
        n /= 2; 
    }
    binary = binary.reverse();
    System.out.println(binary);
    for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++){
      if(binary.charAt(i) == '1'){
            count++; 
            System.out.print("" + count);
        } if(count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
        }    
     else {
         count = 0; 
        }
    }
    System.out.print(maxCount);
}
```

With the code above the count variable would not increment when n = 439(110110111). It would print 1211111 instead. As result, maxCount was 2 instead 3. However, when I used the following code below the count variable incremented as expected when n=439(120120123). As result, maxCount was equal to 3.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        String binaryNum = "";
        int count = 0, maxCount = 0; 
        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder(); 
        while(n != 0){
            binaryNum = Integer.toString(n % 2);
            binary.append(binaryNum);
            n /= 2; 
        }
        binary = binary.reverse();
        System.out.println(binary);

        for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++){
                count = (binary.charAt(i) == '1') ? count + 1 : 0;
                System.out.print("" + count); 
             if(count > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
            }    
        }
        System.out.print(maxCount);
    }
```

I would like to understand why the output of count is different when I used the first code option vs. the second code option. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Typo: you reset `count` to 0 here `count = ... ? count + 1 : 0;`. The initial code (a bit convoluted) does it when `if(count > maxCount)` is false. Not when `if(binary.charAt(i) == '1')` is false.

Comment: Just to be more precise: `condition ? opt1 : opt2` is ternary operator because it has 3 operands. But since we don't know if Java will not introduce other operator with 3 operands in the future it is safer to call this operator by its real name which is "conditional operator". In other words it is not ***the*** ternary operator, but ***a*** ternary operator.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for your response. Your explanation revealed that it was my logic that was causing the output to be different and not the use of the conditional operator vs. if condition. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a closing } making the code run strangely.

Your intention on the first example was probably as below. I have just moved the } so that the else attaches to the if {} block that you had in mind.

```
if(binary.charAt(i) == '1'){
            count++; 
            System.out.print("" + count);
        if(count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
        }
     } else {
         count = 0; 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. You are correct, the structure above is exactly what I had in mind. Also, I tried out your response and it yielded the correct output for the count variable. It amazing how a simple curly brace changes things. Thanks Again. Take Care!